# chebyshev nodes - formula for general interval

Tags: numerical-methods, chebyshev-polynomials, octave

Could you help me write elegant form of formula for Chebysev nodes in $[a,b]$ ?
Size of vector of points is $n$.

I am working with octave, but the most important thing is: How to formulate it clear and elegant ?

Comment: It seems that your question is about the best way to write a program from Octave; since this is primarily a coding question, it seems off-topic here and should rather be on stackoverflow.

Comment: `nodes = cos(pi/n*((1:n)-.5))`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately I did forget to say that I have interval $[a, b]$. What is form of nodes in case of interval ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $n$ Chebyshev  interpolation points $x_k=\cos\frac{\pi}2 \frac{2k+1}{n}\in[-1,1]$, $k=0,1,2,\dots, n-1$. Use $x_k$ to define
 $z_k\in [a,b]$  as following
$${z_k} = \frac{{a + b}}{2} + \frac{{b - a}}{2}{x_k}$$

```
k=0:(n-1);
nodes = cos( (pi/2) * (2*k+1)/(n) ) ;
nodes = (a+b)/2 + nodes*(b-a)/2;
```

Comment: tell me, what it should be written for n+1 nodes ?

Comment: just write  $n+1$ instead of $n$

Comment: so k=0:n  or k=1:n+1

Comment: k=0:n and also .../(n+1) instead of .../n